# Problema con PostAsJsonAsync() en Blazor

Tags: post, blazor

Recibo respuesta del servidor en blazor 400 cuando intento llamar al método Post,
mi código es el siguiente:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorCRUD.Shared;
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>...</h1>

@code{
      private List<Asistencia>? lista;

      protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
      {
       lista = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Asistencia>>("api/asistencia");       
      }

      private async Task RegistrarAsistencias()
      {       
       var result = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<List<Asistencia>>("api/asistencia", lista);

       if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
       {
        lista = null;
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/response");
       }
       else
       { 
         //tengo codigo aqui       
       }
     }    
}
```

Y el controlador es el siguiente:

```
using Models;
using Servicios;
using Servicios.Interfaces;
using Asistencia = Models.Asistencia;

namespace BlazorCRUD.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AsistenciaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IOrdenServicios ordenAsistencias;

        public AsistenciaController(IOrdenServicios ordenAsistencias)
        {
          this.ordenAsistencias = ordenAsistencias;
        }

        [HttpGet] //El get no me da ningun error
        public async Task<List<Asistencia>>? GetAsistencias()
        {
          return await Task.FromResult(ordenAsistencias.GetAllAsistencias().Result);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<bool> Post(List<Asistencia> asistencias)
        {
         return await Task.FromResult(ordenAsistencias.RegistrarAsistencias(asistencias).Result);
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
          return View();
        }
    }
}
```

El servicio ya está agregado:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrdenServicios, OrdenServicio>();
```

Lo que mi aplicación hace es que manda a llamar una API que hice con Unit Of Work + Patrón repositorio y todos los métodos se les hizo prueba mediante consola y no da ningun error pero al momento de querer ejecutar el método Post, pues tengo este problema, ahora, no sé si tena algo que ver o a lo mejor tengo un error conceptual, pero cuando mando solo el objeto Asistencia en vez de una lista de ese objeto, ahí si me funciona pero yo lo que necesito mandar es una lista de esos objetos no uno solo.

La consola del navegador (Chrome) me arroja el siguiente resultado:

POST https://localhost:7225/api/asistencia 400

**EDIT**

Así es como está el archivo index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorCRUD.Shared;
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>Asistencias</h1>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="+1 Hora" @onclick="aumentar" class="btn btn-success" disabled="@estatus" />
    <input type="submit" value="-1 Hora" @onclick="disminuir" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="@estatus" />   
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar Asistencias" @onclick="RegistrarAsistencias" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@estatus" />
</div>

<hr>

@if (lista == null)
  {
    <p><em>Cargando..</em></p>
  }
else
  {
   <table class="table table-striped align-middle table-bordered">
       <thead class="table-success">
           <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Nombre</th>
               <th>Hora</th>
               <th>Lector</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            @foreach (var userdata in lista)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@userdata.IdEmpleado</td>
                    <td>@userdata.Nombre</td>
                    <td>@userdata.Hora</td>
                    <td>@userdata.Lector</td>                    
                </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
   </table>
  }

@code{
      private List<Asistencia>? lista;
      private List<Asistencia>? listaAux;   
      protected bool estatus = false;

      protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
      {
         lista = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Asistencia>>("api/asistencia");
         listaAux = lista;
      }

      private async Task RegistrarAsistencias()
      {
        //var result = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/asistencia", lista);
  
        var result = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<List<Asistencia>>("api/asistencia", lista);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        {
          lista = null;
          NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/response");
         }
        else
        {
          estatus = true;       
          NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
      }

      private void aumentar()
      {
        for (int i = 0; i <= lista.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            listaAux[i].Hora = lista[i].Hora.AddHours(1);
        }
   
        lista = listaAux;
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
       }

       private void disminuir()
       {
         for (int i = 0; i <= lista.Count - 1; i++)
         {
            listaAux[i].Hora = lista[i].Hora.AddHours(-1);
         }

         lista = listaAux;
         NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
       }
  }
```

La clase del servicio que se registró en el servidor es:

```
public class OrdenServicio : IOrdenServicios
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public OrdenServicio(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    //Este es el GET del lado del servidor en blazor
    public async Task<List<Asistencia>> GetAllAsistencias()
    {
       //Toda la lógica que no tiene ningun problema
    }

    //Aqui es donde llamo la lógica para el POST
    public async Task<bool> RegistrarAsistencias(List<Asistencia> asistencias)
    {
       DataSet ds = new();
       int contador = 0;
       bool response = false;
        
       using(var context = _unitOfWork.UOFConnect())
       {
          await context.Repositorios.AsistenciaRepository.BorrarTabla();
          var result = context.Repositorios.AsistenciaRepository.RegistrarAsistenciasTemporales(asistencias);
            
          foreach (var item in result.Result)
          {
            ds = context.Repositorios.AsistenciaRepository.RegistraAsistencias(int.Parse(item.IdEmpleado)).Result;
                
            if ((int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0] != 0)
            {
               contador += 1;
            }
          }                
       }

       if (contador > 0)
          response = true;            

       return await Task.FromResult(response);
      }
   }
```

La interfaz que implementa el método para registrar en la clase de servicio es:

```
   public interface IOrdenServicios
   {
      public void CrearOrden(Orden T);
      public void Eliminar(Guid Id);
      public Task<Orden>? ConsultarById(Guid? Id);
      public Task<List<Orden>>? GetAll();
      public void Actualizar(Orden T);
      public Task<List<Asistencia>> GetAllAsistencias();
      public Task<bool> RegistrarAsistencias(List<Asistencia> T);
   }
```

La clase asistencia es la siguiente:

```
   public class Asistencia
   {
      public string? IdEmpleado { get; set; }
      public DateTime Hora { get; set; }
      public string? Nombre { get; set; }
      public string? Departamento { get; set; }
      public string? Lector { get; set; }
      public string? Evento { get; set; }
      public string? Tipo { get; set; }
      public string? RutaImagen { get; set; }
   }
```

Espero que esto ayude en algo, gracias. Y sólo por si acaso la cadena de conexión del appsettings.json:

```
    {
      "Logging": {
         "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
         }
      },
     "ConnectionStrings": {
         "SQL": "Data Source=192.x.xx.xx; Initial Catalog=BLAZOR; User Id=cassa; Password=vasti",
         "Pruebas": "Data Source=admin\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=KodotiSells; User Id=sa; Password=administrador",
         "Vasti" : "Data Source=192.x.xx.xx; Initial Catalog=VastiNet; User Id=cassa; Password=vasti"
      },
     "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el codigo de la clase Asistencia? Por que si te da error 400 podría ser algo del "bindeo" del modelo. Al ver la definicion de la clase Asistencia podemos verificar propiedades requeridas e incluso armar una pequeña demo para ver lo que sucede. Pero generalmente es porque no puede "bindar la ruta con el modelo que se envia". Esperamos que completes la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Amigo José A. Fernandez ya puse mas código despues de EDIT, gracias.